# Jquery missing in wordpress 5.6

Tags: wordpress

I just installed a fresh WP 5.6 and I realized that there is no JQuery at all inside the blog (it is still inside wp-includes/jq/jquery, but it is not loaded by default)

1. Has JQuery been removed by default from WP ?
2. I am trying to develop a WP plugin that uses Jquery (ajax calls) in wp-admin:
   Should I manually load Jquery with wp_enqueue_scripts ?

> ```
>    add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
>    function my_jquery_enqueue() {
>       wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
>     }
> ```

Comment: As far as i know It's still in there!!!! The files might be corrupted. Did you download the file directly from wordpress.org?

Comment: yes, I used wp cli for that.